# Sub-string case

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, substring

After reading a web-page i got the following text.

```
Weekend of March 23 - 25, 2018
Title
Weekend
Gross
Weeks

Pacific Rim: Uprising
$28.1M
$17M
1

Spider Man: Home Coming
$37.8M
$12M
3
```

My problem is that i can't get all titles just like 
`Pacific Rim: Uprising` & `Spider Man: Home Coming` (in this example) so do you suggest any solution for that, i really tried a lot of codes but nothing worked for me, it seems to be so hard since i can't depend on something for example it would be easier to copy what goes after "title:" and stop when there is empty line.

**Update**
i have figured out that all titles can be found on lines number 30,46,62... but how to write a code that copies specific lines! can you help me with that?

Comment: there's no similarities which might be used to identify the titles :( ...

Comment: Read lines with `line_no %5 == 1` (assuming you have texts starting with movies titles.)

Comment: Does the title look like this : `Title Pacific Rim: Uprising` or just `Pacific Rim: Uprising` ??

Comment: actually i have another html version it's too long but may be easier

Comment: @zackraiyan it's just like the latter for sorry!

Comment: If you have a list of movie names,it'ld be easy to get what u want :)

Comment: @zackraiyan please can you read the update section

Comment: wait i'll try to post an answer

Comment: and is every line separated ?? and are these lines in some html file ?

Comment: Read a line at a time.  Count lines since the last blank line.  First line after a newline is the title.

Comment: have anyone figured a solution?

Comment: gimme a minute...i'm posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a parser. But, in order to parse text, there has to be some underlying structure present. Luckily, there is just enough in this case to be serviceable.

```
Pacific Rim: Uprising
$28.1M
$17M
1

Spider Man: Home Coming
$37.8M
$12M
3
```

Each movie entry consists of a single identifying pattern: 2 lines that contain "$" signs, followed by a simple integer. So a simple solution consists of 2 methods: a method to read all the contents of the file, one line at a time, and a method to parse a movie entry, once it is located:

```
public class Movie
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public decimal Gross {get;set;}
  public decimal Weekly {get;set;}
  public int Weeks {get;set;}
}

public void ReadMovies()
{
  List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("movies.txt");
  int cursor = 0;
  while (cursor < lines.Length)
  {
    if (lines[cursor].Contains("$"))
    {
      movies.Add(ParseMovie(lines, ref cursor));
    }
    cursor++;
  }
}

public Movie ParseMovie(string[] lines, ref int cursor)
{
  Movie result = new Movie();

  // this method is called when we reach the gross dollar figure, so 
  // we have to back up to get the title

  result.Title = lines[--cursor];

  // these lines assume that the parse methods will succeed; if the
  // underlying structure of the text is more uncertain, these should be
  // replaced with the 'TryParse' pattern

  result.Gross = decimal.Parse(lines[++cursor].Trim('$', 'M'));
  result.Weekly = decimal.Parse(lines[++cursor].Trim('$', 'M'));
  result.Weeks = int.Parse(lines[++cursor]);

  // we return from this method with the cursor on the last line
  // of the movie entry -- this will be incremented when we return
  // in the ReadMovies method

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on a few assumptions :

1. You have a list of all the movies(not the HTML/retrieved movies but a list of all movies released)
2. You have list(the html file-as u mentioned) that has movie titles and details , line after line,one below the other

Firstly get the names of all the movies.Google for it and add them to a text file.Then read the text file and add the names/titles to a list.Then we create a list of the retrieved movie names.Then we compare two lists for matches and return the title(match)

Follow the below code snippet :

```
List<string> movieList = new List<string>;
movieList.Add(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\movies.txt"));
List<string> retrievedList = new List<string>; ///The list of retrieved movie list
retrievedList.Add(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\retrievedmovies.html"));
foreach (var item in retrievedList)
{
    if (movieList.Contains(item) == true)
    {
    continue;
     MessageBox.Show(item)
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...If it doesn't , please leave a comment before down-voting